# Find text in table and smoothly scroll to that position on table and also highlight this row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a simple table with some data and i want to scroll to a specific position based on date & highlight that row and based on the which day of Ramadan it is.

Let us say its 13 Ramadan which would be on `25-04-2021` then i have to scroll to that position and highlight the row in RED or any other color.
So far i am finding text and changing the color and i am doing same for scroll but scroll is not working not sure where i am doing it wrong..

This page feature is specially required for mobile version so that user is scroll to the right position on page etc

https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/jOyLWNR

```js
//$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('05-05-2021'):last").offset().top);
//$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('25-04-2021')").offset().top);
$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('25-04-2021')"));
$("tr:contains('25-04-2021')" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-w ">
  <table class="ramadan-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Day</th>
        <th scope="col">Ramadan</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">13-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Tuesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">1</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">14-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Wednesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">2</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">15-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Thursday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">3</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">16-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Friday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">4</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">17-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Saturday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">5</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">18-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Sunday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">6</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">19-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Monday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">7</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">20-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Tuesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">8</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">21-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Wednesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">9</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">22-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Thursday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">10</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">23-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Friday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">11</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">24-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Saturday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">12</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">25-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Sunday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">13</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">26-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Monday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">14</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">27-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Tuesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">15</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">28-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Wednesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">16</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">29-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Thursday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">17</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">30-04-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Friday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">18</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">01-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Saturday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">19</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">02-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Sunday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">20</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">03-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Monday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">21</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">04-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Tuesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">22</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">05-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Wednesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">23</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">06-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Thursday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">24</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">07-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Friday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">25</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">08-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Saturday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">26</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">09-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Sunday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">27</td>
 
      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">10-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Monday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">28</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">11-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Tuesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">29</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        
        <td class="Date" data-label="Date">12-05-2021</td>
        <td data-label="Day">Wednesday</td>
        <td data-label="Ramadan">30</td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).scrollTop($("*:contains('25-04-2021')").parent('tr').offset().top);`

Jquery scroll needs the offset of html tag.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qtkwr7ny/

Comment: Thanks it working will add smooth scrolling to it..

Comment: Glad to help you.